Cuál es el orden de complejidad del segundo for?
Estoy viendo el orden de complejidad, hice esto y quiero ver el orden del segundo for.
static void marcaConCeros(int[] vec) {
    boolean esta = true;                      //Este vale 1
    for (int i=1; i<vec.length; i++ ) {       //Este vale 1+2(n-1)+1(n)
        esta = true;                          //Este vale 1(n)
        for (int j=0; j<=i-1; j++ )           //Este es el que quiero saber.
              esta = esta && vec[j] != vec[i]; //Este vale 5n^2
        if (!esta)                
           vec[i]=0;                          //Este vale 1(n)
    }
}


No entiendo del todo como estás calculando, pero te puedo decir que dado el siguiente algoritmo
static void marcaConCeros(int[] vec) {
    for (int i=1; i<vec.length; i++) {    
        for (int j=0; j < i; j++ ){
           //
        }
    }
}

Lo de dentro del primer for se ejecuta n-1 veces y lo de dentro del segundo se ejecuta n(n-1)/2 veces. Para el primer for creo que es clara la razón va de i=1 a i<vec.length y para el segundo tenemos que sigue la siguiente secuencia de ejecución:
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + x

Lo que es una progresión aritmética, entonces la función que describe la cantidad de ejecuciones del segundo for es:
         x (x + 1)
f(x) =  -----------
             2

Pero x = n - 1, ya que el primer for ejecuta siempre una vez menos, entonces:
          n-1 ( n-1 + 1)     (n-1)n
f(n-1) = ---------------  = --------
                2               2 

Que en notación Big O de todas maneras es O(n2)

Ahora entendí, muchas gracias.

La forma en la que lo estaba haciendo era por ejemplo:  for (int i=1; i<vec.length; i++ )  // el i = 1 vale 1, el i < vec.length vale 2(n-1) y i++ vale 1(n), y me da 3n -1, está mal??

@GonzaloBenitez No te podría decir si es correcto o no, esto lo vi hace muchos años. Para mí lo importante es la complejidad algorítmica, por tanto, es necesario analizar las instrucciones como un TODO. Me resulta más simple de esa manera, al contrario de como tú lo estás haciendo que es analizando una a una las instrucciones. Por ejemplo, para un for, para mí lo importante no son los argumentos, si no lo que está dentro del bloque

Si, la forma en la que lo haces vos es importante, pero en la universidad me piden que cuente cada instrucciones para hacer la complejidad asintótica.
